# Too many authentication failures for *username* в случае большого количества ключей

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-key

Есть достаточно большое количество ssh-ключей, все с фразами.
В `.ssh` директории в файле `config` всё, что надо прописано (Host, HostName, PreferredAuthentications, IdentityFile, User/Port если надо).
PreferredAuthentications указан для всех `publickey`.
Добавляю ключи через `ssh-add`.
К первым серверами 3 подключается хорошо, проблемы начинаются с 4+.
Я всё понимаю, что мой клиент начинает подставлять все добавленные ключи, начиная с первого. А типичный сервер прекращает это безобразие после 3 попытки.
При этом использовать `IdentitiesOnly`, конечно, не хочется, т.к. по новой вводить фразу нет смысла, иначе зачем добавлять в агент.
Есть ли какое-то решение (кроме как держать только минимальный набор ключей или ключи без фразы)?

Конфиг:

```
Host foobar
HostName 1.1.1.1
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo.bar
```

[image: ssh-add log]

С ключами всё хорошо (после переноса файла с открытым ключом рядом к закрытому):

```
PRIVKEY=~/.ssh/ruvds.com
TESTKEY=~/.ssh/ruvds.com.pub
diff <( ssh-keygen -y -e -f "$PRIVKEY" ) <( ssh-keygen -y -e -f "$TESTKEY" )
```

Ключ генерировал так:

```
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -f ruvds.com
```

**UPD**: Спасибо @aleksandr-barakin за ответ. Это решило мою проблему. На скриншоте выше не работало, потому что я по ошибке использовал открытый ключ не от того закрытого.

Comment: Добавьте `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_very_secret_key`.

Comment: пример конфига вопросу не помешал бы...

Comment: @0andriy он там есть

Comment: @fat-zer виноват, добавил

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: а что это за опция `-o` программы *ssh-keygen*? не вижу такую ни в системном man-е, ни в интернетных копиях.

Comment: Не, не, есть, надо чуть ниже полистать (у меня kubuntu 18.04): `-o      Causes ssh-keygen to save private keys using the new OpenSSH format rather than the more compatible PEM format.  The new
             format has increased resistance to brute-force password cracking but is not supported by versions of OpenSSH prior to
             6.5.  Ed25519 keys always use the new private key format.`
Кстати, у меня по ходу заработало, я просто перегенерировал открытый ключ из закрытого, хотя вчера делал тоже самое (пока продолжу эксперименты)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообще стоит ознакомиться с ответами на этот вопрос: [Is it reasonable to have multiple SSH keys?](https://superuser.com/q/121307/454489).

> При этом использовать `IdentitiesOnly`, конечно, не хочется, т.к. по новой вводить фразу нет смысла, иначе зачем добавлять в агент.

если в память программы *ssh-agent* добавлен расшифрованный секретный ключ **с именем файла**, то программа *ssh* будет использовать (при наличии опции `identitiesonly yes`) этот «агентский» ключ при условии, что в опции `identityfile` вы указали файл с **публичной частью** этого ключа, и имя этого файла (как и происходит по умолчанию) образовано добавлением суффикса `.pub`.

---

практика.

1. имеются два файла (секретная и публичная части одного и того же ключа):

   ```
   ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   если вдруг публичная часть потерялась, восстановить несложно [с помощью опции `-y` программы *ssh-keygen*](http://blog.barak.in/2011/08/restore-ssh-public-key-from-private-key.html)
2. имеются такие строки в файле `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   host сервер
   identitiesonly yes
   identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   обратите внимание: указать надо именно публичную часть ключа, ту, что с суфиксом `.pub`.
3. добавляем секретную часть в программу *ssh-agent* (вводим пароль к ключу в ответ на запрос):

   ```
   $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
4. проверяем, что имя файла с секретной частью ключа программе *ssh-agent* известно (приведён пример вывода):

   ```
   $ ssh-add -l
   2048 SHA256:хэш.ключа /полный.путь.к.домашнему.каталогу/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
   ```
5. подключаемся:

   ```
   $ ssh сервер
   ```

   пароль (которым зашифрована секретная часть ключа) **не** запрашивается: использовалась уже расшифрованная секретная часть ключа, хранящаяся в памяти программой *ssh-agent*.

---

p.s. идея почерпнута из совета [отсюда](https://blogs.gnome.org/danni/2013/04/11/identitiesonly-ssh-agent/).

Comment: Пробовал ещё до того, как создать вопрос. Во-первых, меня смущает, что почему-то не для всех ключей показывает путь. Во-вторых, не работает. Результат моей попытки добавил в первый пост в виде скриншота (вы уж простите, но писать более или менее развёрнутый ответ это просто издевательство). После попробовал ещё открытый ключ положить рядом с закрытым (чтобы оба лежали в .ssh) - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Хотя для некоторых ключей, после добавления и последующим выводом (-l) путь показывает. Насколько я могу судить, я с некоторого времени просто стал по другому генерировать ключи.

Comment: при выполнении трёх условий у меня — работает: 1. обе части ключа должны лежать в одном каталоге и имя должно отличаться только суффиксом `.pub`. 2. имя файла (с секр. частью) должно быть известно программе *ssh-agent*. 3. в секципи `host` конф. файла должен быть указан путь к публичной части ключа.

Comment: @YuraShinkarev, попробуйте оставить в секции `host` только два или три параметра: `identityfile`, `identitiesonly` и, при необходимости, `hostname`. (а также убрать глобальные параметры). ну и приведите версию программы *ssh* (и *ssh-agent*, если отличается)

Comment: Насчёт пути. Удалил полностью из config-файла запись, перенёс открытый ключ, чтобы он нигде не фигурировал. При добавлении секретного ключа - тоже самое. Я сейчас смотрю на другой ключ, который в старом формате, и который при добавлении корректно показывается (имеется ввиду путь), там такие различия. Старый ключ: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,0E885C7EFAE2B504682683A96BC7A229
<key here>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
`, новый `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
<key here>
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98070/discussion-between-yura-shinkarev-and-aleksandr-barakin).